# Batch appending groups of images using imagemagick

Tags: command-line, imagemagick

I want to use ImageMagick’s [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) script to append two images horizontally.

This is easily done with `convert +append input1.jpg input2.jpg output.jpg`.

I have a directory of jpeg files however. They look like this:

```
1996-0011-1 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg
1996-0011-2 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg
2001-0006-1 MEF FooBar.jpg
2001-0006-2 MEF FooBar.jpg
…
```

The first four digits are a year, the next four digits are some running number. `-1` is the left part, `-2`the right part of the intended output file. The remaining part of the file name is a string with a variable number of white spaces.

How do I append these groups of two images using `convert` automatically? I imagine it can either be done by working on the first, second, … pair of files independent from their file name or by grouping these files according to their file name (this would be beneficial for users who don't have just two images).

I use OS X. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What OS are you running on? Sounds very much like a shell-type solution to feed ImageMagick the right inputs..

Comment: @tanantish I am running OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two things:

- You have access to a reasonably modern version of GNU bash, or a compatible shell
- The identifier portion is always `yyyy-nnnn-` followed by one or more digits (in sequence) followed by something else

then you can use [bash string manipulation](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/) and shell wildcard expansion to accomplish what you want.

Run this in a directory where the files `1996-0011-1 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg`, `1996-0011-2 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg`, `2001-0006-1 MEF FooBar.jpg` and `2001-0006-2 MEF FooBar.jpg` already exist.

```
$ ls -1
1996-0011-1 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg
1996-0011-2 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg
2001-0006-1 MEF FooBar.jpg
2001-0006-2 MEF FooBar.jpg
$ mkdir old
$ for filename in *.jpg; do
>   test -f "$filename" && convert +append ${filename:0:10}* "${filename:0:9} ${filename:12}" && mv ${filename:0:10}* old/; done
$ ls -1
1996-0011 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg
2001-0006 MEF FooBar.jpg
old/
$ rm -r old
$
```

The way this works is by, for each .jpg file in the directory:

1. test if the file exists and is a regular file
2. if the file exists, then run `convert`, passing the first ten characters of the file name (starting at character position 0, extracting 10 characters) to shell wildcard expansion to be provided as parameters to convert, followed by the first nine characters of the file name followed by a space followed by everything from the 12th character onwards (you can adjust this portion to get the type of output file name you want; make sure to make the corresponding adjustment to the `mv` invocation)
3. if `convert` ran and was successful, move all input files into a separate directory, to get them out of the way

At the end, you will have the output files in the current directory, and all input files will have been moved into the directory named `old`. Make sure to test the above snippet on non-critical data first.

Comment: Curisoity, would there be a better way to append the file suffix than say, `${filename:0:10}-${filename:$[${#filename}-12]:${#filename}-output.jpg` ?

Comment: @tanantish Probably, but the OP left the output file name format unspecified.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks Michael for your help. Unfortunately the commands did not work as expected. I ended up with `1996-0011-1-output-0.jpg` and `1996-0011-1-output-0.jpg` files on the one hand and hundreds of files like `output-0.jpg` (counting up.) on the other hand in the original folder. No files were appended. Any ideas? Thank you again.

Comment: @lejonet Not off the top of my head. Can you run the snippet again, but replace `convert` with `echo` and remove the `&& mv ... old/` part? That will print the arguments that are actually being fed to `convert` which should help point toward the problem. (echo isn't perfect, but it should be good enough for the time being, and it's a trivial change to make.) Also, note that my snippet assumes *exactly* the file name format specified in your question. For anything different, you will have to adjust the string manipulation indexes and lengths accordingly.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling This is the output: -`1996-0011-1 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg 1996-0011-2 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg 1996-0011-output.jpg`
-`1996-0011-1 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg 1996-0011-2 BEG Foo Bar Foo Bar.jpg 1996-0011-output.jpg`
-`2001-0006-1 MEF FooBar.jpg 2001-0006-2 MEF FooBar.jpg 2001-0006-output.jpg`
-`2001-0006-1 MEF FooBar.jpg 2001-0006-2 MEF FooBar.jpg 2001-0006-output.jpg` Thanks again.

Comment: @lejonet Oops, I think I see the problem (or at least, *a* problem). Try it now and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It works, thank you very much. I did not specify the output format. Would it be possible to keep the rest of the file name instead of "output"? Thanks again!

Comment: @lejonet I think that will do.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thank you Michael. I will award the bounty as soon as technically possible. Your help is outstanding.